# Indexing a position of value change

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list (or it can be 1-D numpy array) filled with zeros and ones:

[image: screenshot]

Is there an easy pythonic way to extract the index of items on a transition from one to zero and vice versa?
For example for above screenshot it should be something like: [1350, 1600, 1970, ...]

Comment: Please post sample I/O  so that I can give you exactly what you need. Also, which index would you like? Suppose `L[[1350]=0` and `L[1351]=1`, do you want `1350`, `1351`, or `(1350, 1351)`?

Comment: It doesn't really matter, just one of the indexes. "Signal" is from image scan line. I thought that there is some method without iterating over the series, that I wasn't aware about, but I guess this is it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to differentiate your data using numpy.

```
import numpy as np
x = [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0]
result = np.diff(x)
print np.where(result!=0)
#(array([ 4,  8, 11, 13]),)
```

This will give you the point before each transition.

Answer (score 0):

```
answer = []
for i in range(len(L)-1):
    if L[i] != L[i+1]:
        answer.append((i,i+1))
```

You could also use the itertools pairwise recipe:

```
def pairwiseCheck(L):
    answer = []
    a,b = itertools.tee(L)
    next(b, None)
    for i, (x,y) in enumerate(zip(a,b)):
        if x != y:
            answer.append((i, i+1))
    return answer
```